# Facebook graph api: Can i use /search and /{id} in 1 request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to call /search and /{id} in 1 request instead of 2? where id is a result of /search?

If so, would i be limited to the id of the first result, or could i call /{id} for each /search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the search type, for example if you search for a User via first/last name like

```
/search?type=user&q=Mark%20Zuckerberg&fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,link
```

you can specify the `fields` parameter with the fields you want to query. The result look like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10101640953722381", 
      "first_name": "Mark", 
      "last_name": "Zuckerberg", 
      "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10101640953722381/"
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind that you only can access public fields with the search.

Comment: I'm interesting specifically in the /search?type=place endpoint. I'd like to batch /search?q=x&type=place and the results i.e. /result[0].id in one request. Will this also work?